# Topology of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

I am having trouble understanding examples from my notes:

1. Let $S = [0,1]$ and let $A = [0, \frac{1}{2}).$ Then $A$ is open, but not closed. The set of limit points $A$ with respect to $S,$ $A^\prime = [0, \frac{1}{2}].$

For this example, I am having trouble understanding why $A = A^\circ$ (set of interior points of $A$), because if we look at $0 \in A,$ it doesn't seem that we can find an $\varepsilon >0$ such that the neighborhood $B_{\varepsilon}(0)$ is completely contained in $A.$ Even if we take $\varepsilon$ as small as possible, won't $B_{\varepsilon}(0)$ still stick out of $A$? I don't think $0$ can be an interior point... Here's a picture I quickly made in paint to show how I am viewing this:
[example 1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzLVq.png)

2. Let $S = (0,1)$ and $A = (0, \frac{1}{2}].$ Then $A$ is closed in $S.$

I'm heaving trouble understanding why $A$ would be closed here... wouldn't $0$ be a limit point that's not in $A$? We have that $0 \not\in S$ but $B_{\varepsilon}(0) \cap (A \setminus \{0\}) \ne \emptyset$ for every $\epsilon > 0.$

3. $S = [0,1] \cup [2,3]$ and $A = [0,1]$. $A$ is open in closed in $S.$

Confused for a similar reason as in example 1, since the neighborhoods of the endpoint $0 \in A$ will stick out of $A$ for every $\varepsilon > 0.$ Won't this make $A$ not open?

4. $S = (0,1) \cup (1,2),$ $A = (0,1).$ $A$ is open and closed in $S.$

Isn't $0 \not\in A$ a limit point of $A$? If $A$ doesn't contain all of its limit points, I don't see how it can be closed in $S$

5. $S = [0,1) \times [0,1), A=[0,\frac{1}{2}) \times [0,\frac{1}{2}).$ $A$ is open and not closed. I am not seeing how $A$ is open if we can look at the neighborhoods of $(0,0) \in A$ and observe that none of them are contained in $A$ (similar reason for confusion as example 1): [How I'm thinking of this particular example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxu3V.png)

Clearly I'm missing something fundamental here, could someone please explain what is wrong with my reasoning? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question,

> Even if we take $\varepsilon$ as small as possible, won't $B_{\varepsilon}(0)$ still stick out of $A$?

No. $S=[0,1]$, and we know NOTHING about anything not in this interval. So for example if $\varepsilon=1/10$ then $B_{\varepsilon}(0)=[0,1/10)$. Note that $-1/20$ for example would NOT be in this ball, because $-1/20$ doesn't exist! We have no idea what negative numbers are in this case!

For your second,

> wouldn't $0$ be a limit point that's not in $A$?

Again, no! This is for the same reason. If $S=(0,1)$ we have no idea what $0$ is! What is $0$? It's not in $S$, so it doesn't exist.

For your third and forth questions, the answers should be the same as first and second respectively.

Only elements in your space exist, you know nothing else. If $0$ doesn't exist, it can't be a limit point, can it?

Comment: Thank you, I understand now! Great answer